# Запись новой информации в файл

Tags: java

Изучаю низкоуровневые способы работы с потоками в Java. Для копирования информации из одного файла в другой написал такой метод:

```
public static void writeTo(String fromFile, String toFile) throws IOException {
    FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(fromFile);
    FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(toFile);

    byte buffer[] = new byte[1000];
    while (fileInputStream.available() > 0) {
        int count = fileInputStream.read(buffer);
        fileOutputStream.write(buffer, 0, count);
    }

    fileInputStream.close();
    fileOutputStream.close();
}
```

Далее использую этот метод вот так:

```
String file1 = reader.readLine();
String file2 = reader.readLine();
String fileResult = reader.readLine();

writeTo(file1, fileResult);
writeTo(file2, fileResult);
```

Проблема в том, что при копировании информации из второго файла, информация которая уже содержалась в результирующем файле просто испаряется. Не получается найти информацию о том как этого избежать... Есть идея каждый раз копировать то, что уже содержиться в файле в ОЗУ, а потом записывать снова вместе с новой информацией, но это бред какой-то.

Более высокоуровневые и готовые решения прошу не предлагать. Мне это нужно для обучения, а не для работы.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Для того, чтобы новый данные добавлялись в файл, а не перезаписывали старые,  необходимо созадть поток, связанный с файлом таким образом:

```
FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(toFile, true);
```

Если второй аргумен принимает значение `true`, то данный будут записываться в конец файла, а не в начало.
Подробнее [здесь](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileOutputStream.html#FileOutputStream(java.io.File,%20boolean)).

Answer (score 1):

Вот, свежий код, думаю разберетесь, у меня работает

```
File sdcard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
File from = new File(sdcard,"first");
File to = new File(sdcard,"second");
StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
try {
    BufferedReader br_from = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(from));
    BufferedReader br_to = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(to));
    String line_from;
    String line_to;
    while ((line_to = br_to.readLine()) != null) {
       result.append(line_to);
       result.append('\n');
    }
    while ((line_from = br_from.readLine()) != null) {
       result.append(line_from);
       result.append('\n');
    }
    br_from.close();
    br_to.close();
}
catch (IOException e) {}

try
{
    FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(new File(sdcard, "second"), false);
    writer.write(result.toString());
    writer.flush();
}
catch (IOException e){}
```

Тоесть, сначала записываем в `StringBuilder` весь текст из принимающего файла, потом добавляем  весь текст из отправляющего файла и записываем в принимающий. Если работаете в Android вам нужны еще 2 пермишна в манифесте

Comment: Мой вопрос как раз и заключается в том как правильно соединить поступивший текст с имеющимся.

Comment: @faoxis, тоесть вам нужно взять тексты из двух файлов и закинуть оба в третий файл? Или с первого копировать во второй так, чтобы старый не испарялся?

Comment: мне надо добавлять текст в файл `fileResult` так, чтобы то, что в нем уже было оставалось + добавлялось новое.